# How do I access the coverage database generated by coverage.py and get a list of all executed statements?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py, nox

The coverage report only shows the percentage, and I would like to know all executed statements.

Eventually, I need a map in which the key is the statement and the value is True(Executed)/False(Not Executed).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML report to see what statements are executed and not.  You can access the data through the Coverage Data API: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.3.2/api_coveragedata.html

What will you be doing with the executed/not-executed data?